# How to move and object to specific coordinates?

Tags: java

Im making a java game, and the objective is to doge bullets. Im wondering if there is any easy way to use .getX() and .getY() of a specific object to make the bullet move towards that object? Im trying to have the bullet either chase the players X and Y coordinates or get the players coordinates and go to those. I am very new to java, so the more simpler the better. I have tried a few scripts from different forums, but nothing seems to work. So far I have just been rendering rectangles for my bullet and character.

Comment: So... is this a game using sprites? Do you have any code to show? Have you made any attempt to address your problem before you asked for help?

Comment: If you are new to Java then I recommend that you take the time to learn the basics of Java before delving into graphics.  It will make your efforts much easier.

Comment: @WJS  I’m not looking for any graphics right now, I’m looking for a movement pattern the would follow coordinations of a player